# Sequelize - How to use a where clause for joined tables

Tags: jquery, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to include a where clause, with a function, in a query that has more than one level of joined tables, as in:

```
    return Database.Sequelize.where(
        Database.Sequelize.fn('lower', Database.Sequelize.fn('unaccent', Database.Sequelize.col(attribute))),
        'LIKE',
        Database.Sequelize.fn('lower', `%${accentsHandler(param.toLowerCase())}%`))
}

A.findAll({
     where:[Op.or]:[whereByParamUnnaccented('a', '$B.C.field$'),
                    whereByParamUnnaccented('a', '$B.field$')]
     include:[{
       model: B,
       include:[{
         model:C
       }]
     }]
})
```

But instead, I'm getting this error:

> Error retrieving missing FROM-clause entry for table "$B->C" SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "$B->C".

**UPDATE 1**
I didn't really replicate what I'm trying to do, I updated the query. But, basically, I would like to be able to make an or condition using fields from different tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the clause in the include.

Example with belongsTo relation :

```
Post : id, title, description
Tag: id, name
PostTag : id, fk_post_id, fk_tag_id
```

Models :

```
Post.associate = (models) => {
    models.Post.belongsToMany(models.Tag, {
        as: "Tag",
        through: "PostTag",
        foreignKey: "fk_post_id",
        otherKey: "fk_tag_id",
    })
}

Tag.associate = (models) => {
    models.Tag.belongsToMany(models.Post, {
        as: "Post",
        through: "PostTag",
        foreignKey: "fk_tag_id",
        otherKey: "fk_post_id",
    })
}
```

Clause in the include :

```
db.Post.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 1, // where on Post
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Tag,
            as: "Tag",
            where: {
                name: "Tag1", // where on Tag
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the scenario, as I had forgotten to include one important detail.